# Time zone of user in profile as optional field

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some users put their timezone with location. For example `India (GMT+5:30)`. It helps other to understand availability of an user.

Can it be an optional field in user profile?

Comment: That assumes users keep regular hours. I've occationally answered questions on sleepless nights ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think general users are interested in knowing when a specific user is available here and that shouldn't be an intention too; for all generic purposes. Still, specifying your location is optional which can imply your timezone, if they are interested anyhow.

So adding the field is hardly worth the change.